# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models  
class jaga(models.Model):
     user_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Username')
     password =models.ForeignKey(max_length=50, verbose_name='pwd')

     def __unicode__(self):
          return(self.user_name, self.password)
```

The error thrown is,

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

where have i went wrong?

Comment: What is the **full** traceback of the exception?

Comment: Also, how do you call `jaga`? (also, i think i fixed your identation issue but i wasn't sure how you wanted to build you class, but that looks "good" to me except that you declare `user_name` outside a function which i tend to dislike)

Comment: Post full traceback with exception location

Comment: This is not your problem, but your `__unicode__` method returns a tuple of strings instead of a single unicode string. You will certainly run into trouble because of this.

Answer (score 3):

The foreign key field needs to point to another model

```
password = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, verbose_name='pwd')
```

But I presume this is a typo because the password field should probably not be a Foreign Key